# Word mail merge with two records per page

Tags: microsoft-word, mail-merge

I'm trying to build a mail merge that has columns from two different records on the same page, a set of cue cards for an MC of a cabaret or variety show.

It could be a list of future performances for the performer leaving the stage (the previous row), their show media and web presence, and performer name and intro for the current performer and their act.

Or, it could be a list of future performances for the performer leaving the stage (the current row), their show media and web presence, and performer name and intro for the next performer and their act.

Right now, my mail merge document splits each performer in half with a well placed page break and the I go in after the merge and delete the record breaks, bringing the exiting performer and the entering performer onto the same cue card.

Answer (score 1):

Set up the merge document as a label sheet where each label is one-half the page (2-up, 1 column). Then print it on plain paper.

Comment: Check e.g. Avery 5912 template as an example.

Comment: Good idea! I'll give it a test poke and see if it does what I need.